# Inserting a node into XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am wondering if anyone can help me with a problem I am having.

I am using XSLT version 1 to transform some source XML, part of which looks like this:

```
<tr parent="ID0E4B" zylevel="3" type="categoryhead">
 <td colname="1">Utilities 1.61%</td> 
 <td colname="2">1.61</td>
 <td colname="3">300,000</td>
</tr>
<tr parent="ID0EOB" zylevel="2" type="categorytotal" >
 <td colname="1">Total </td>
 <td colname="2"/>
 <td colname="3">17,567,240</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to be able to create a tr node similar to the tr
node in the source xml and insert it between the two tr nodes
in the above example. The node to insert should like this:

```
<tr parent="ID0EGWAE" zylevel="4" type="detail">
  <td colname="1">Other securities</td>
  <td colname="2">1.61</td>
  <td colname="3">335,207</td>
</tr>
```

Right now the XSLT processor is about to print the second tr
node in the topmost example. The desired output should look like this:

```
    <tr parent="ID0E4B" zylevel="3" type="categoryhead">
        <td colname="1">Utilities 1.61%</td>
        <td colname="2">1.61</td>
        <td colname="3">300,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr parent="ID0EGWAE" zylevel="4" type="detail">
    <td colname="1">Other securities</td>
    <td colname="2">1.61</td>
    <td colname="3">335,207</td>
   </tr>
    <tr parent="ID0EOB" zylevel="2" type="categorytotal" >
      <td colname="1">Total </td>
      <td colname="2"/>
      <td colname="3">17,567,240</td>
    </tr>
```

Any help that anyone has would be much appreciate it. I have to
admit to being clueless on this one.

Comment: You are not giving enough information. Please show your current XSLT code and a full XML/XHTML input file. Otherwise, nobody can diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!-- identity template -->
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1"><!-- Inserting given content after the first tr -->
            <tr parent="ID0EGWAE" zylevel="4" type="detail">
                <td colname="1">Other securities</td>
                <td colname="2">1.61</td>
                <td colname="3">335,207</td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rudramuni TP. After a little tweaking to my needs that appears to have done the trick.